# How to concatenate multiple columns with separators but ignore some of columns based on condition in R?

Tags: r, concatenation, multiple-columns

Hi there i would like to concatenate columns containing strings or blanks or NA's with ";".
So lets take example below:

```
Actor1<- c("Driver","NA","","")
Actor2<- c("President","Zombie","","")
Actor3<- c("CEO","Devil","","")
Actor4<-c("Priest","","Killer","Mayor")

df_ex <-data.frame(Actor1, Actor2, Actor3, Actor4)
```

i tried this:

```
df_ex %>%
  mutate(combined= paste0(Actor1,";",Actor2,";",Actor3,";",Actor4))
```

but obviously the result is wrong, e.g.:

```
df_ex[3,]
```

outcome in combined column is this: 
;;;Killer

I would expect outcome to be:
Killer.

Note: there NA's and blanks "" as well which id like to ignore.

thanks in advance ,
cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am far far away from being a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) expert, but I'll put here a [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) approach:

```r
Actor1 <- c("Driver","NA","","")
Actor2 <- c("President","Zombie","","")
Actor3 <- c("CEO","Devil","","")
Actor4 <-c("Priest","","Killer","Mayor")

library(tidyverse)

data.frame(Actor1, Actor2, Actor3, Actor4) %>%
  mutate_all(~str_replace(., pattern = "NA", replacement = "")) %>% 
  unite(col = "combined", sep = ";", remove = F) %>% 
  mutate(combined = str_replace_all(combined, pattern = "^[:punct:]|[:punct:]$|[:punct:]{2,}", replacement = "")) %>% 
  select(-combined, everything(.), combined)

#>   Actor1    Actor2 Actor3 Actor4                    combined
#> 1 Driver President    CEO Priest Driver;President;CEO;Priest
#> 2           Zombie  Devil                       Zombie;Devil
#> 3                         Killer                      Killer
#> 4                          Mayor                       Mayor
```

If you want just some of the columns, you can pass them in `unite`:

```r
data.frame(Actor1, Actor2, Actor3, Actor4) %>%
  mutate_all(~str_replace(., pattern = "NA", replacement = "")) %>% 
  unite(Actor2, Actor4, col = "combined", sep = ";", remove = F) %>% 
  mutate(combined = str_replace_all(combined, pattern = "^[:punct:]|[:punct:]$|[:punct:]{2,}", replacement = "")) %>% 
  select(-combined, everything(.), combined)

#>   Actor1    Actor2 Actor3 Actor4         combined
#> 1 Driver President    CEO Priest President;Priest
#> 2           Zombie  Devil                  Zombie
#> 3                         Killer           Killer
#> 4                          Mayor            Mayor
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Actor1<- c("Driver","NA","","")
Actor2<- c("President","Zombie","","")
Actor3<- c("CEO","Devil","","")
Actor4<-c("Priest","","Killer","Mayor")

matrix_ex <-cbind(Actor1, Actor2, Actor3, Actor4)
#apply(df_ex,1,paste,collapse=";")
x<-apply(matrix_ex,1,function(x){paste(x[!(is.na(x)|x==""|x=="NA")],collapse=";")})
x

[1] "Driver;President;CEO;Priest" "Zombie;Devil"                "Killer"                      "Mayor"                                    
> cat(paste(x,collapse="\n"))
#Driver;President;CEO;Priest
#Zombie;Devil
#Killer
#Mayor
```

To answer the comments:

```
df_ex <-data.frame(Actor1=Actor1, Actor2=Actor2, Actor3=Actor3, Actor4=Actor4,rnorm(4))

df_ex$concat<-apply(df_ex[c("Actor1","Actor3")],1,function(x){paste(x[!(is.na(x)|x==""|x=="NA")],collapse=";")})
df_ex$concat

df_ex$concat2<-apply(df_ex[c(1,3)],1,function(x){paste(x[!(is.na(x)|x==""|x=="NA")],collapse=";")})
df_ex$concat2
```

Comment: This is exactly what i want to avoid: those unneccesary separators in front due to na's or blanks

Comment: one more question: lets assume i have more columns and want to concatenate only chosen ones, how to apply it to your code?

Comment: lets say i want to concatenate Actor1 and Actor 3 only

Comment: ```selectedcolumns=c(1,3);x<-apply(df_ex[selectedcolumns],1,function(x){paste(x[!(is.na(x)|x==""|x=="NA")],collapse=";")})

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below, using `do.call` + `paste`

```
df_ex$combine <- gsub("\\bNA;?\\b|;{2,}|;$","",do.call(paste,c(df_ex,sep = ";")))
```

such that

```
> df_ex
  Actor1    Actor2 Actor3 Actor4                     combine
1 Driver President    CEO Priest Driver;President;CEO;Priest
2     NA    Zombie  Devil                       Zombie;Devil
3                         Killer                      Killer
4                          Mayor                       Mayor
```

Comment: Thomas, in line 2 there's still a `;` at the end.